# Issue loading shared library in Java

Tags: java, linux, windows, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I wish to make a java implementation based on a C++ library using the JNI. Unfortunately, when I wish to use the shared library in java it can not be found. The problem with this shared library is that it links another shared library. I have two different cases one works (but shouldn't be used) and the other one doesn't.

The Ana lib must always be static. The Clara lib must always be shared. It works when the Bob lib is static, but it should be shared and it should include Ana and Clara.

Case 1 (Works and can be loaded in the correct java.library.path).

sharedlibJava.so links: staticlibAna.a staticlibBob.a sharedlibClara.so

Case 2 (Doesn't work because it can't be loaded even though the java.library.path is correct).
sharedlibBob.so links: staticlibAna.a and sharedlibClara.so (the basic c++ implementation is tested and it works without problems)

sharedlibJava.so links: sharedlibBob.so (the java implementation should be available using this new shared library).

The problem is that when I try to load the library it doesn't even find it in the correct java.library.path even though it is located there.

I would really appreciate any feedback regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your path locations on LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Alternatively, put them into -Djava.library.path

If you have compiled code properly, I don't think you should experience issues while accessing shared library.

If you compile one code as shared lib, and then refer to it by linking other code with shared lib, it should work just fine

```
cc -g -shared -fpic c/recipeNo023_AnotherFunction.c -o lib/libAnotherFunction.$(EXT)
cc -g -shared -fpic -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/$(ARCH) c/recipeNo023_HelloWorld.c -L./lib -lAnotherFunction -o lib/libHelloWorld.$(EXT)
```

Then, you should be able to call the code by passing lib location inside -Djava.library.path

```
java -Djava.library.path=:./lib -cp target recipeNo023.HelloWorld
library: :./lib
Hello world!
Hello from another function!
```

For the full sample code, take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo023